# How to change the height?

Tags: html, css

Look... I am learning css/html and all that but I am not very good in it till yet... soo look... http://leesh.de/stack-overflow-question I need the message with Get your own ... under the second green line... I know how to do that with position absolute, but then I have to use margin/left-right/width to center it... and I would have to do that for every device, so now I used text-center to like I said center it... but now I don't know how to change the position that it would be under the green line... Sry for my bad english :/ I hope you can help me

Comment: If you post your CSS & Html code you have more chance getting some help

Comment: You took down the site at the link you posted and never posted the code you were talking about so this question doesn't stand a chance of being useful for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your`row-fluid` codes below your `<p class="border-bottom"></p>`
Like this.

```
<p class="border-bottom"></p>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="text-center get-link-message"> Get your own # right now! &nbsp;<a href="http://mmd.to/leecreate"><u>Click here to get it...</u></a><br>Copyright 2017 Leesh.de. Crafted with love ♥ in Saint. Petersburg, Russia</p>
</div>
```

[image]
Don't need position absolute.